# Check if linear operator is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis

I have an operator $A: C_{L_1[0,1]} \rightarrow C_{L_2[0,1]}, Ax(t)=t^3\int_0^1x(\tau)d\tau $. 
Notation can be bizzare, so 
$ C_{L_1[0,1]} $ is a set of functions which metric is $ \rho(f,g)= \int_a^b |f(x)-g(x)|dx $ 
and 
$ C_{L_2[0,1]} $ is the same, but it's metric is $ \rho(f,g)=(\int_a^b(f(x)-g(x))^2 dx)^{1/2} $. 
As the topic says, I want to prove that it's bounded, i.e. 
$ \exists c:   ||Ax||_{C_{L_2[0,1]}} \leqslant c||x||_{C_{L_1[0,1]}} $.
Ok, here's the scariest part. H o w. I guess I missed something really important or just having trouble to do the first step. It seems ok for $ C_{L_1[0,1]} $ since it a somewhat classic integral transform (is it?) and I honestly looked up in a book about this case, but what to do in my case is, er, an open question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof is quite simple, once you start to write down the definitions step by step. What you want to prove is that $\| A x \|_{L^2[0,1]} \leq C \| x \|_{L^1[0,1]}$ for some positive constant $C >0$. Note that I am using the more common notation $L^2$ and $L^1$, rather than $C_{L^2[0,1]}$ as you wrote. So let's prove this:
\begin{equation}
\| A x \|_{L^2[0,1]}^2 = \int_0^1 (Ax)(t)^2 \: dt = \left( \int_0^1 x(t) \: dt \right)^2 \int_0^1 t^6 \: dt
\end{equation}
Now taking square roots on both sides, we see
\begin{equation}
\| A x \|_{L^2[0,1]} = \sqrt{\int_0^1 t^6 \: dt} \; \left| \int_0^1 x(t) \: dt \right| \leq C \int_0^1 |x(t)| \: dt = C \|x \|_{L^1[0,1]}
\end{equation}
if we set $C=\sqrt{\int_0^1 t^6 \: dt} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{7}}$ and by pulling the absolute value inside the integral. This shows what we wanted to show!

Comment: And that's when I feel very stupid. Thanks a lot, now this seems obvious (as do most of the problems with a trick but anyway).

Comment: No need to feel stupid ;-) You're welcome.